# How update an image dynamically using data binding?

Tags: image, apache-flex, binding

I have a main.mxml application that lays out my application, it contains a "browse and upload" button. And contains an image to view the users uploaded image like so:

```
<mx:Application
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    import model.myModel;
    import control.myControl;

    // Create data model
    public var model:myModel = new myModel();
    //[Bindable]
    //private var scld_img:Bitmap;

    // Create control
    public var mycontrol:myControl = new myControl(mymodel);

</mx:Script>

<!-- Upload and view -->
<mx:Canvas id="upload" label="1: Upload Image">

   <mx:VBox>
   <mx:HBox>

   <mx:Label text="Upload an image: "/>
   <mx:Button id="btn"
      label="Browse and preview..."
      click="mycontrol.browseAndUpload();"
      buttonMode="true"
      useHandCursor="true"/>

   </mx:HBox>


<mx:Image id="mximg_upld"
   verticalCenter="0"
   horizontalCenter="0"
   source="mymodel.img_scld_bm"/>

</mx:VBox>
</mx:Canvas>
......
```

In my `myModel` class I have a `img_scld_bm` that the `browseAndUpload()` function draws into after scaling it.

My intent is that my `mx:Image` will display the image. As shown here I'm assigning the image `source="mymodel.img_scld_bm"`, this ends up just showing a broken image icon.

I also tried data binding, where in my `myModel` class I have `[Bindable] var img_scld_bm`. And then tried setting my `mx:Image source="{myModel.img_scld_bm}"` .. that didn't seem to do anything either. All this compiles fine, no warnings. I think in this case, I'm not setting a trigger or propertyChange event to update the binding?

Can someone help me understand, or provide an example of how to correctly bind an `mx:Image` source to some bitmap??

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've given, it looks like you need to do two things:

1. Wrap the source with curly brackets.
2. Set the property `img_scld_bm` in the model class.  Bindings will only execute if you *set* the property; it looks like you may be drawing into the `img_scld_bm` that currently exists, but this won't cause the image to update.

Convert this:

`<mx:Image id="mximg_upld" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" source="mymodel.img_scld_bm"/>`

To this:

`<mx:Image id="mximg_upld" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" source="{mymodel.img_scld_bm}"/>`

Then any time you make changes to the `img_scld_bm` in the model, reset the image.source.

Does that work?